# C++ stringstream operator >> read internal buffer to the end, but read() method - not

Tags: c++, stringstream

I've filled a `stringstream` with data in cycle. About 2mb of data. Then I need to read the data.

First, I use such cycle:

```cpp
while (ss >> str)
{}
```

At the end of the cycle, `str` contains the last chunk of data. But in this case, I can't read `\r\n` symbols.

Well, I try to use this method:

```cpp
int length = 20.000.000;
char * buffer = new char[length];
ss.read(buffer, length);
```

And the `buffer` contains little more than half of the data. After flushing.
Why is this?

Comment: How do you know it if you don't inspect read's returned value? What is flashing? Are you developing Arduino?

Comment: In the case of `ss.read()` make sure you add a null terminator to `buffer`, if you are treating it as a null-terminated string afterwards. Or at least use `ss.gcount()` to ensure you don't exceed the bounds of the valid data. Perhaps you are simply seeing garbage data that `read()` didn't write into `buffer` to begin with.

Comment: Is `20.000.000` a typo? I'm surprised it compiles but i imagine evaluates to `20`. Please show a [mre]